# Cant get Azure Cognitive Services to access my blob container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-services

I have a resource group with Cognitive Services and a storage account with a blob container. They only accept connections from a selected IP range. The blob is public (for now).

I can do operations with Cognitive Services on publicly available files and get it to work. I can also access my blob in my browser. But once i try to pass that same url in an operation in Cognitive Services i get "Bad request and the following error.

```
"code": "InvalidImageURL",
    "message": "Failed to download the image from the submitted URL. The URL may either be invalid or the server hosting the image is experiencing some technical difficulties."
```

I have given my Cognitive Services an Azure role as Storage Blob Data Reader. If i check Access control for the storage account its listed my Cognitive Services resource as Storage Blob Data Reader.

If i allow all networks to use the services its working fine, but thats not an option with production data. Seems this ip range is somehow blocking Cognitive Services resource to access my storage account.

What am I missing to be able to make them work together?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Nicklas, 

I have the same issue. I did find encouraging signs in the docs where it says you can let `Trusted Azure Services` access overriding the network rules (Exceptions). However I couldn't get it to work either. 

Are you passing a SAS URL (of blob) to the cognitive service as well?

Docs Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-cli#trusted-access-based-on-system-assigned-managed-identity